# Rear red light with seat bag

Tags: accessories, bags

My bike has this red reflective light right below the seat (I don't know its name), and I'm thinking of buying a seat bag such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00165P4X6). Won't the light be covered? Isn't this potentially dangerous? How does one fix it normally?

Comment: Is the red reflective light below the seat an actual light (as in, battery-powered) or simply a reflector?

Comment: It's only a reflector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reflective brand name tab on the rear of that seat bag is a light holder. You will most likely need to remove the light from the seat post. Hopefully it has a clip styled mount, otherwise you can get a light that has a clip mount.

Comment: +1 - This is the answer. I have a different brand of seat bag, but it has the very same sort of tab that my rear light clips onto.

Comment: Of course, the OP doesn't actually have a light, just a reflector, which probably doesn't have any sort of clip. But getting a light to clip on is good!

Comment: The reflector on the bag is sometimes times more-effective at reflecting lights than the "free" reflector that's included with bikes.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only reflective you have currently, then you might want to buy a separate battery operated active light, and place it below the bag on the stem.

I would assume the bag is designed to fill most space available, and hence would obstruct the existing light.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little sad that the bag doesn't come with a proper reflector, but a clip-on unit can be added, as suggested.  The flashing red LED clip-on tail lights are quite inexpensive, will run continuously for a week or two on one set of batteries, and are well worth the investment, though make sure that there is at least some degree of passive reflector function in the clip-on and/or the cloth of the bag as well.